# Do the various African state organizations plan to do anything about the projected man-made famine in Sudan?

Tags: africa, civil-war, food, sudan

[According](https://edition.cnn.com/2024/03/18/africa/sudan-hunger-forcible-recruitment-jazira-intl-cmd/index.html) to the UN WFP, the RSF is stealing food on a massive scale in Sudan, including the seeds for future crops. The WFP paused their distribution due to said theft. Various other organizations project that consequently 7 million people are at risk of starvation in the upcoming months.

Do the various African state organization plan any sort of (military) intervention, to facilitate the aid?

(Back in the day [UNAMID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations%E2%80%93African_Union_Mission_in_Darfur) was authorised to deploy nearly 20,000 troops and protect humanitarian operations, but its mandate has ended in 2021. Also, the areas of fighting are much more widespread now than just Darfur.)

Comment: Isn't the whole sad state of Sudan a result of previous interventions in the area?

Comment: FWTW, the SAF was [also](https://www.middleeasteye.net/news/sudan-war-army-rsf-profit-smuggling-food-fuel-starlink) accused of stealing ([ibid](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/dec/13/soldiers-accused-of-widespread-looting-from-homes-near-sudanese-capital)), but at least not straight from the UN.

Comment: This question could be improved by expanding less common acronyms before using them, to help clarify things for readers who are less familiar with the situation in Sudan in 2024.